# accessing nested inner class struct from outer class

Tags: c++, class, nested

```
class A
{
 class B;
 B::data myData; //Error: incomplete type not allowed.

    class B
    {
    public:
        struct data
        {
        int number;
        };
    };
};
```

In the code above, how could I declare a member variable of type data in class A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B` must be *defined* before you use it in the declaration of `A::myData`:

```
class A
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        struct data
        {
            int number;
        };
    };

     B::data myData;
};
```

Comment: Okay. I thought there might be a way to let the compiler know that B::data is a struct before actually defining it, similar to declaring class B;

Comment: Even if you could, you still wouldn't be able to use it to define a data member:  the type has to be _complete_.

Comment: James is correct, the only way you can use a type before it is fully defined is as a pointer, because pointers take up constant space

Comment: @DanF:  Or in a reference type, or as a parameter or return type in a function declaration, or as a template parameter, or... there are lots of scenarios in which incomplete types are usable.

Comment: I didn't know you could use incomplete types as return types, parameter types, or template parameters.  The more you know!

Answer (score 3):

I think all you need to do is put the class definition in front of the declaration of the variable.  The compiler has no idea what is inside `class B`, only that it exists, until it encounters the actual definition of the class

Answer (score 0):

Use scope specifiers and make sure you don't use the type until after its defined in the file:

```
class A
{   
    class B
    {
    public:
        struct data
        {
        int number;
        };
    };

    B::data myData;
};
```

Also, note that forward-declaration doesn't work unless you're just using a pointer to the class.  When you create an instance of the class like you have, it needs the definition to that class available to it immediately.